# How to receive parameter values in google Sheet script and use parameter it in sql query

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following googleSheet URL:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19D-ApX1M_vuGUVOSIUrxrpyVna6pxBk86abTfmXRzBI/edit#gid=0?empId=1203&DepId=MCA

I want to pass query String parameter in google sheet url and use it in to sheet script

I use this code in sheet script

```
var url = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl();
```

above url give me only

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19D-ApX1M_vuGUVOSIUrxrpyVna6pxBk86abTfmXRzBI/edit

I want to use all parameters in url like

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19D-ApX1M_vuGUVOSIUrxrpyVna6pxBk86abTfmXRzBI/edit#gid=0?empId=1203&DepId=MCA

how it is possible to get parameters `empId` and `DepId` from googleSheet in Script

Comment: some one help me, I am stuck !

Comment: we don't have access to your URLs as it's private. we have no idea what project your working on and how you came up with that URL.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible by using the Google Apps Script's Spreadsheet Service. It could be possible by using the creating a web app and using event object. For further details see [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).